# Command Palette Search Include All Files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am making use of the `files.exclude` setting in VSCode, but would still like to be able to search for the file using the Command Palette.

Is there a way to prevent?:

> Configure glob patterns for excluding files and folders in fulltext searches and quick open. **Inherits all glob patterns from the `files.exclude` setting.**

[VSCode Default Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings)

**Note:** I am not talking about the *Search* tool in the side bar. I am specifically wanting the Command Palette Search functionality to not be affected by the `files.exclude` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default `search.exclude` configuration that inherits all `files.exclude` patterns, and is set to:

```
"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true,
    "**/*.code-search": true
},
```

You can therefore rewrite some patterns for QuickSearch by rewriting this in your local `settings.json`.

Comment: EDIT: It did not work to add `"search.exclude": { "*": false }`.

Comment: Apologies for the back-and-forth with accepting your answer. This does work, but requires me to type in the full relative path to the file.
Example: if `files.exclude: { ".vscode": true}`, and `search.exclude: {"*": false}`, then typing in `settings.json` shows nothing, but typing in `.vscode/settings.json` shows the file in the search.